# Make GIFBUILDER Image and return the filepath

Tags: svg, typo3, filepath, typoscript

I use SVGs for page icons on a TYPO3-site. The page icons are stored as ressource media in the page properties. Usualy I use them also for open graph and twitter images. But Open Graph does not support SVG.

Now I would like to use GIFBUILDER to convert SVG to PNG and return the file path of the converted GIFBUILDER-Image. I could not find any hint, so I ask you for help.

Bsp:

```
headerData {
    60 = FILES
    60 {
        #gets image form media tab of page
        references {
           table = pages
           uid.data = page:uid
           fieldName = media
        }
**# This returns the path of the ressource media**
        renderObj = TEXT
        renderObj {
           typolink {
              parameter.data = file:current:publicUrl
              forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
              returnLast = url
           }
           wrap = |,
        }
        **# But I have SVGs so I have to convert them. Therefor empty         renderObj**
        renderObj >

    renderObj = GIFBUILDER
    renderObj {
       XY = 200,200
       format = png
       quality = 100
       10 = IMAGE
       10.file = file:current:publicUrl
    }
    stdWrap {
       listNum = 0
       # Use logo image if none is available
       ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
       ifEmpty.cObject.typolink {
          parameter = {$defaultsocialimg}
          forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
          returnLast = url
       }
       wrap = <meta property="og:image" content="|">
    }
     }
}
```

Does anyone has an idea?
Thanks
Martin

Revision 1:

I changed my TYPOSCRIPT and combined the answers of from below (thanks you you two) and made this:

```
ogimage = IMG_RESOURCE
ogimage {
    10 = FILES
    10 {
        references {
           table = pages
           uid.data = page:uid
           fieldName = media
        }
        begin = 0
        maxItems = 1

        renderObj = TEXT
        renderObj {
           typolink {
              parameter.data = file:current:publicUrl
              forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
              returnLast = url
           }
        }
    }
    file = GIFBUILDER
    file {
        XY = 200,200
        format = png
        10 = IMAGE
        10.file.data = file:current:publicUrl
        10.file.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
    }
    wrap = |
}
```

Now I really get the path of the image. But 1. the image is empty/white, 2. the path is not absolute despite "forceAbsoluteUrl = ". The 2. is not a big problem. But the first ... I also tried a jpg-image in case that GIFBUILDER might have problems with svg.

Maybe the file:current:publichUrl is not valid at that position anymore (file.10.file). I tried LOAD_REGISTER, but could not really imagine where to place.

Revision 2:

OK, nearly finished: The new TS:

```
lib.ogimage = FILES
lib.ogimage {
    references {
        table = pages
        data = levelmedia: -1, slide
        fieldName = media
    }
    begin = 0
    maxItems = 1

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {

        5 = LOAD_REGISTER
        5.imagepath.data = file:current:publicUrl

        #TEST if the path is correct
        10 = TEXT
        10.value.data = REGISTER:imagepath

        #20 = IMG_RESOURCE later for path-output
        20 = IMAGE
        20 {
            file = GIFBUILDER
            file {
                XY = 200,200
                format = png
                10 = IMAGE
                10.file.import.data = REGISTER:imagepath
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the correct image if the ressource media is <> svg. If my ressource media is SVG, i get this Error:

### 1476107295: PHP Warning: imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in /usr/www/users/abppjo/typo3/typo3_src-8.7.9/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Imaging/GraphicalFunctions.php line 2867 (More information)

:´-(

Answer (score 0):

`GIFBUILDER` is to use under an `IMAGE` or `IMG_RESOURCE` ContentElement:

```
lib.test = IMAGE
lib.test.file = GIFBUILDER

lib.testUrl = IMG_RESOURCE
lib.testUrl.file = GIFBUILDER
```

If you want to get the path to the `GIFBUILDER` image you have to use `IMG_RESOURCE`.

Comment: Thanks René. Really true, what you say. Please have a look above. Maybe wie can crack the nut.

Comment: Try to use an `renderObj = COA` and register the `file:current:publicUrl` in an `LOAD_REGISTER` and use this Variable in your Gifbuilder

Comment: Hi René.  Yes great, the path now reaches the file-property in GIFBUILDER. Nevertheless problems appeared (sie above).

Answer (score 0):

Try below typoscript.

```
lib.image = IMAGE
lib.image {
    10 = FILES
    10 {
        references {
           table = pages
           uid.data = page:uid
           fieldName = media
        }
        renderObj = TEXT
        renderObj {
           typolink {
              parameter.data = file:current:publicUrl
              forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
              returnLast = url
           }
        }
    }
    file = GIFBUILDER
    file {
        XY = 200,200
        format = png
        10 = IMAGE
        10.file.data = file:current:publicUrl
        10.file.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
    }
    wrap = |
}
```

Comment: Hi TYPO3 Developer, thank you for your help. I checked your TS together with the hin of René. Little problems still exists. Thanks for having a look :-)